# Page that works in Android Browser doesn't work in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

We are designing an app that as part of its functionality needs to let users interact with this page:

http://m.bridgestonetire.com/catalog

This page works fine in the device browser and formerly worked in our webview, but now users cannot click on the Year / Make / Model buttons.  The other functions on the page ARE clickable.

In searching here on similar issues the answers always seem to be around changing the underlying webpage, which we cannot do.  Is there anything we can do to make our webview more compatible with that page?  Webview settings are as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getActionBar().hide();
    Constants.setCViewAndRenderFonts(this, R.layout.web_layout);
    adviser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.tireAdvisor);

    WebViewClient tclient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            L.d( "loading url: " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    };
    adviser.setWebViewClient(tclient);
    adviser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    adviser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    adviser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    adviser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    adviser.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    adviser.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    adviser.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    adviser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    adviser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36");

    String mobileUrl = "http://m.bridgestonetire.com/catalog";
    String desktopUrl = "http://m.bridgestonetire.com/catalog";

    adviser.loadUrl(desktopUrl);
    adviser.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    adviser.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    adviser.clearCache(true);
    adviser.clearFormData();
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realized you are using JQuery in your web page, and the link that "data-href" is tryin to open is a .json file.

for example "MAKE" option :

```
<input type="hidden" name="make" value="" data-href="http://m.bridgestonetire.com/bin/fst/api/vehicle/1/make.json" />
```